# Can I get wifi/bluetooth combo driver of rtl8821ce pcie mini card for Ubuntu 20.04.3?

Tags: drivers

I have HP-15da2180nia Laptop. It has rtl8821ce wireless card. I can use wifi but in the
bluetooth setting it says 'No adapter found' . How to setup bluetooth? Is there any wifi/bluetooth combo driver for rtl8821ce? Please help.

Device:
HP-15da2180nia

wireless controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Do you see Bluetooth adapter in bios?